# Android read handset proxy settings

Tags: android, proxy, settings

If user behind proxy he can set proxy settings in android handset under 'access point option' is there a way i can read proxy settings from android handset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use android.net.[Proxy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Proxy.html) class to get info about Proxy Host and Port.

Comment: This class, unfortunately, seems to be deprecated. It says use the standard java VM values...

Comment: But what is that java VM attributes?

Answer (score 2):

The android.net.Proxy class will only give you the host and port - my proxy required user and password also.

I was able to dig through the Android source and found where the other proxy values are stored.  This works in the Android debugger - I haven't tried this on an actual device.

```
String proxy;
int port = -1;
String user;
String password;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers/current");
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, 
            new String[]{"proxy", "port", "user", "password"}, 
            null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    proxy = cursor.getString(0);
    port = cursor.getInt(1);
    user = cursor.getString(2);
    password = cursor.getString(3);
}
```

(Android source of [com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/providers/TelephonyProvider.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/providers/telephony/TelephonyProvider.java;h=c31d88c8665ff6d6943dc9d92edd7fac18cbae4c;hb=refs/heads/froyo-release) that contained the URI and column names.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing the [Android Proxy Library](http://www.android-proxy.com/2012/02/android-proxy-library-apl-best.html) that try to abstract the access to proxy settings for every Android version. You can easily get the proxy settings currently selected by the user.